# Doctrine 2 Querybuilder How to stop Doctrine 2 turning integer into string

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am trying to learn Symfony and I am reading out some data with Doctrine 2. I noticed that the type returned from my Querybuilder is string(2) "10" and not integer, but I need Int since I am trying to build a Google Line Chart. I just can't figure out how to turn it into an Integer. Can anyone help on below Query? Thank you very much in advance.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o');

return $qb

        ->select('SUM(CASE WHEN o.plantType LIKE :shrub then 1 ELSE 0 END) as Shrub')     
        ->addSelect('SUM(CASE WHEN o.plantType LIKE :tree then 1 ELSE 0 END) as Tree')
        ->addSelect('SUM(CASE WHEN o.plantType LIKE :annual then 1 ELSE 0 END) as Annual')
```

Comment: In your connections configuration, try adding "options: {20: false}" This basically sets PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES to false which, for some reason that I forget, causes integers to be returned as integers.

Comment: Thank you Cerad. I am just trying to figure out how to do that in Symfony 5, since I am totally new to it to see if that works.

Comment: In the file config/packages/doctrine.yaml, add the options line under dbal

Comment: Tried  doctrine: dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        options: {20: false} but nothing changed. I suppose I am being stupid here?

Comment: I'd have to setup a test case.  I guess you can always just typecast the individual result.

Comment: I was hoping to typecast somehow directly into the query. But how do I do that in ->select('SUM(CASE WHEN o.plantType LIKE :shrub then 1 ELSE 0 END) as Shrub')

Comment: Typecast in php: $shrubCount = (int)$result['Shrub'];

Comment: I actually run the result directly in a function to re-structure it for google Charts. The function is generic so that i can re-use it. Would you know if it's possible to have the typecasting directly in QueryBuilder ?